# Thin Client Lubuntu over PXE Server with DHCP and TFTP

Tags: lubuntu, dhcp, nfs, pxe, tftp

I have 10 old computers (like thin clients) without HDD. So i decided to use Lubuntu as Operating System. In my work we have a PXE server with DHCP and TFTP, they built a debian distro before and for the menu.cfg, they used boot=live but in lubuntu they use nfs and boot must be boot=casper, so here my problem begins, i tried to change the vmlinuz and initrd, but then i am getting a kernel panic error.
Is there a script that i can merge squashfs and initrd.gz, so the thin clients will begin directly over initrd.gz.
OR is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `memdisk` from `syslinux-common` package to boot using ISO image directly though TFTP.

1. Copy `memdisk` & ISO images to TFTP root
2. Add menu entries to PXE configuration file, Example:

   ```
   LABEL slitaz
       MENU LABEL ^Slitaz.iso
       TEXT HELP
   Testing boot from iso.
       ENDTEXT 
       KERNEL memdisk
       APPEND initrd=slitaz-cooking.iso

   LABEL mini_ubutnu
       MENU LABEL Mini-Ubuntu
       KERNEL memdisk
       APPEND initrd=ubuntu_mini.iso
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible to run Lubuntu over the network. I had to dig into the initrd, but managed to run lubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64 over the network.
To run, you need to unpack the image and open access to it via tftp and nfs. Need the following keys during boot:

```
append initrd=.../casper/initrd netboot=nfs nfsroot=... ip=dhcp file=/cdrom/preseed/lubuntu.seed
```

- … - Your path.
- netboot - specifies that the cd image should be mounted via nfs.
- ip - configure network interface via dhcp.
- file - I don't know why, I just left it.

You can add "quiet" and "splash" to "pretty boot".

---

### Server organization example:

1. Boatload Server IP: 192.168.0.99
2. Working folder: /pxe_home/
3. The image is stored: /pxe_home/img/lubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
4. The image is mounted in /pxe_home/lubuntu/
5. tftp home directory: /pxe_home/
6. Nfs server configured:

   /pxe_home/lubuntu/ *(ro,insecure,root_squash,subtree_check,crossmnt)

   The “crossmnt” flag is required if the image is being mounted.
7. Configuration for pxelinux.0:

   label lubuntu
   menu label lubuntu
   kernel lubuntu/casper/vmlinuz
   append initrd=lubuntu/casper/initrd netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.0.99:/pxe_home/lubuntu ip=dhcp file=/cdrom/preseed/lubuntu.seed

One problem. For some reason, booting over the network does not set up DNS, although DHCP transmits this information. Because of this, Lubuntu does not see the Internet. However, manually setting DNS addresses solves the issue.

### Why and from where:

Next, I'll go through the initrd boot order and show where the boot options come from.

- /init
  87: By including "conf/conf.d/default-boot-to-casper.conf" sets "BOOT=casper" . Separate boot parameter "boot=casper" can be omitted.
  Loading conf/uuid.conf for future verification of the mounted disk.
  279: The file "/scripts/nfs" is just a dummy. Then its functions are called: mount_top, mount_premount, which do nothing useful.
  285: mountroot (/scripts/casper:898) is imported from /scripts/${BOOT} (/scripts/casper).
- /scripts/casper
  7: mountpoint=/cdrom
  8: LIVE_MEDIA_PATH=casper
  923: Scripts /scripts/casper-premount are being run.
  If you set the boot flag "debian-installer/driver-update=" then you can add drivers (scripts/casper-premount/10driver_updates:94).
  935: The actual mount happens in do_netmount (/scripts/casper:204).
  213: To boot via nfs, the NETBOOT variable (key netboot, /scripts/casper:69) must be set to "nfs", or any unexpected value. This will run do_nfsmount (/scripts/casper:229).
  242 Mounting cd in $mountpoint=/cdrom (scripts/casper:7).
  243: Checking mounted directory with is_casper_path(/scripts/casper:85) and matches_uuid(/scripts/casper:97)functions:

  - is_casper_path: Check that /cdrom/casper is an existing directory and that it contains a root system image (*.squashfs file)
  - matches_uuid: Checks if the conf/uuid.conf file loaded in /init:87 matches the /cdrom/.disk/casper-uuid-* file. To ignore the check, you need to set the boot key "ignore_uuid". I needed this because I lost the .disk folder when unpacking. After I figured out the mounting, there were no more problems with this check.

Then everything loads by itself.

Answer (score -1):

Look into https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PXEInstallMultiDistro

I was once able to successfully boot lubuntu over the network with ease (as a live cd). I do not know whether you are looking for a live cd option or if you want to have a true thin client solution. However, I have recently been having troubles figuring out how to get NFS working properly. See my post on it..... [What nfs export settings do I need to boot the Ubuntu live discs over a network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359150/what-nfs-export-settings-do-i-need-to-boot-the-ubuntu-live-discs-over-a-network)