# What nfs export settings do I need to boot the Ubuntu live discs over a network?

Tags: apache2, nfs, live-environment, tftp

**End goal:** Have the ability to PxE boot the ubuntu live discs over the network similar to what is seen in [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PXEInstallMultiDistro)

**What has been achieved:**

- PxE server is up and running with gpxelinux.0. Perfectly functional, as I am able to boot other discs over the network using methods such as memdisk.
- pfSense server handles TFTP traffic
- Another server running ubuntu handles nfs-kernel-server as well as apache for hosting files
- Appended to /etc/exports:

  /srv/data   *(ro,sync,all_squash,insecure)
- The boot label in my pxe menu:

  LABEL Ubuntu 12.04.3 Desktop amd64

  ```
  MENU LABEL Ubuntu 12.04.3 Desktop amd64

  KERNEL http://192.168.1.5/pxe/data/isos/linux/ubuntu/ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-amd64/vmlinuz.efi

  APPEND boot=casper netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.1.5:/srv/data/isos/linux/ubuntu/ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-amd64 initrd=http://192.168.1.5/pxe/data/isos/linux/ubuntu/ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-amd64/initrd.lz
  ```

**What occurs:** The client boots up perfectly fine, loads the kernel and initial ramdisk, but when it gets to doing the nfs mount, all it does it this: [image]

**What I want to happen:** Quite simply, I'd want to have the system be able to mount the NFS share and continue booting up

**What I've done to troubleshoot:**

- Using every possible NFS export table I could think of under the sun to get this thing booted.
- Used a program called JFTP to test the connection to the NFS server. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of crying, I found the solution from a random guess.

In the past, i have done a very similar setup to this with perfect success.

In the past, I used Ubuntu 12.04. In this, I am using 12.04.3.

Went to the old releases, got the old .iso and did the same process to get my folder structure the way it should be.

Now everything is perfectly fine.

hope this helps!